# Audio recorded is echoing in mac app using Apple Sample

Tags: cocoa-touch, macos

I need to implement audio recording feature in my mac app.i am using the Apple sample

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AudioDataOutputToAudioUnit/Listings/main_m.html. Everything is working fine .The only issue is that the audio file created is echoing while playing.Please help!Later I checked, Apple sample also has the same problem

Comment: Is the audio being output through speakers while it's being recorded?  Is there any chance that the microphone might be picking up that audio from the speakers, resulting in echo?

Comment: @Josh its through inbuilt speakers.Can u please try this sample u will come to know what exactly happens.whatever is recorded seems as if played twice.Please try apple sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer myself.Just need to comment

```
effectAudioUnitComponentDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_Delay;
```

From CaptureSessionController.m:

Answer (score 1):

From the [description of the sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AudioDataOutputToAudioUnit/Introduction/Intro.html):

> The built application uses a QTCaptureSession with a QTCaptureDecompressedAudioOutput to capture audio from the default system input device, **applies an effect to that audio using a simple effect AudioUnit**, and writes the modified audio to a file using the CoreAudio ExtAudioFile API.

From [CaptureSessionController.m:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AudioDataOutputToAudioUnit/Listings/CaptureSessionController_m.html)

```
/* Create an effect audio unit to add an effect to the audio before it is written to a file. */
    OSStatus err = noErr;

    AudioComponentDescription effectAudioUnitComponentDescription;
    effectAudioUnitComponentDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Effect;
    effectAudioUnitComponentDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_Delay;
```

It looks like this delay is intentional, as part of the demo.

Comment: can u suggest waht should I use.I dont want any effect.I simply want to record an audio without using any effect.I tried commenting the part u mentioned but in that case no audio file is created

Comment: @Swastik Apple's [Getting Started With Audio and Video](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_AudioVideo_iPhone/_index.html) page has links to an AVAudioRecorder class for recording audio and a SpeakHere demo application.  I haven't done much audio programming, so I can't really be of any more help.

Comment: thanx anyway! I saw u answering many mac related questions thats why asked to answer.

Comment: can u answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828430/provide-print-option-from-mac-app